# почему ошибка взаимодействия disnake кнопки?

Tags: python, discord

```py
class PayConfirm(disnake.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.value: Optional[bool] = None
        
    @disnake.ui.button(label = "Перевести", style = disnake.ButtonStyle.primary)
    async def confirm(self, button: disnake.ui.Button, inter: disnake.CommandInteraction):
        print("+")
        self.value = True
            
    @disnake.ui.button(label = "Отмена", style = disnake.ButtonStyle.red)
    async def cancel(self, button: disnake.ui.Button, inter: disnake.CommandInteraction):
        print("-")
        self.value = False
```

минус/плюс выводит в консоль потом "Ошибка взаимодействия". если код нужен дискорд heck1r#0508

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выводит "Ошибка взаимодействия" т.к в вашем коде нет завершающего действия для интеграции. Достаточно любого отправленного сообщения. **Вот как это реализовать:**

```
class PayConfirm(disnake.ui.View): #кнопки для сообщения
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.value = Optional[bool]
    
  @disnake.ui.button(label='Перевести', style=disnake.ButtonStyle.green) #1-я кнопка; label='название кнопки'; style=disnake.ButtonStyle.цвет
  async def confirm(self, button: disnake.ui.Button, inter: disnake.CommandInteraction):
    await inter.response.defer()
    print('+')
    await inter.edit_original_response()
    self.value = True

  @disnake.ui.button(label='Отмена', style=disnake.ButtonStyle.red) #1-я кнопка; label='название кнопки'; style=disnake.ButtonStyle.цвет
  async def cancel(self, button: disnake.ui.Button, inter: disnake.CommandInteraction):
    await inter.response.defer()
    print('-')
    await inter.edit_original_response()
    self.value = False
```

Также заранее могу дать некоторые советы:

- Если нужно чтобы бот что-то выводил в чат, то уберите `defer` и `edit_original_response`, и добавьте `await inter.response.send_message('ваш текст')`, а чтобы сделать этот текст видимый только одному человеку, внесите изменения `send_message('ваш текст', ephemeral=True)`
- Чтобы кнопки работали всего 20 секунд, измените `super().__init__(timeout=20)`
- Чтобы кнопки работали всего 1 раз, то для каждой кнопки после `self.value =`  поставьте `self.stop()`

**Вот доработанный код:**

```
class PayConfirm(disnake.ui.View): #кнопки для сообщения
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__(timeout=20)
    self.value = Optional[bool]
    
  @disnake.ui.button(label='Перевести', style=disnake.ButtonStyle.primary) #1-я кнопка; label='название кнопки'; style=disnake.ButtonStyle.цвет
  async def confirm(self, button: disnake.ui.Button, inter: disnake.CommandInteraction):
    print('+')
    await inter.response.send_message('Успешно', ephemeral=True)
    self.value = True
    self.stop()

  @disnake.ui.button(label='Отмена', style=disnake.ButtonStyle.red) #1-я кнопка; label='название кнопки'; style=disnake.ButtonStyle.цвет
  async def cancel(self, button: disnake.ui.Button, inter: disnake.CommandInteraction):
    print('-')
    await inter.response.send_message('Успешно', ephemeral=True)
    self.value = False
    self.stop()
```

> Если вам помог мой ответ поставьте галочку **:)**

Comment: я конечно хотел только чтобы self.value = ...  но и у вас ошибка в self.value = Optional[bool].

Comment: но я ставлю галочку

Comment: @k4zzak где вы видите ошибку? И второй код, это только для примера, вы можете использовать первый.

Comment: self.value: Optional[bool] = None

Comment: может у вас и self.value = Optional[bool] работает, но он у меня не работает

Comment: @k4zzak у вас имеется `from typing import Optional`? В любом случае раз всё работает то ладно

Comment: разумеется есть :)